# In which folder should I add the .ko file I compiled?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, driver, insmod

So I have compiled the driver for my USB wireless adapter.
Now I need to know where I should copy the .ko file to. The question is really the following:

What is the difference between
**/lib/modules/(uname -r)/build**
and
**/lib/module/(uname -r)/kernel/drivers**
?

Thank you already

Answer (score 0):

When I add the .ko file to
`/lib/module/(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/`
the driver will be used to drive my USB adapter when I start the computer, at least when I execute 'depmod' after copying the file to a folder under `.../kernel/drivers/net/wireless/` or `.../kernel/net/wireless/`

When I copy the driver to a folder under `.../build` the driver which is also a module isn't used to drive my USB adapter when I start the computer. Also when placed under build, 'modprobe' can't find the module after executing 'depmod'.

This actually tells me that .../build is never a good choice for placing a driver.